# Get the n-th range by pattern

Tags: sed, awk, text-processing

My input is like this:

```
start
content A
end
garbage
start
content B
end
```

I want to extract the second (or first, or third ...) `start .. end` block. With

```
sed -ne '/start/,/end/p'
```

I can filter out the garbage, but how do I get just "start content B end"?

Comment: why `sed`? For the efficiency reasons? Because with `awk`, albeit slower, the script is easier to grok in this case.

Comment: i disagree with the "slower" comment

Comment: @pooh You're right, awk is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But anyway, if you want sed - you get sed:)

```
/^start$/{
  x
  s/^/a/
  /^aaa$/{
    x
    :loop
    p
    /^end$/q
    n
    bloop
  }
  x
}
```

The number of a's in the middle match equals to which segment you want to get. You could also have it in regexp repetion like Dennis noted. That approach allows for specifying direct number to the script.

Note: the script should be run with `-n` `sed` option.

Comment: +1 You can use an actual number for *n* instead of a sequence of characters of length *n*: `/^a\{3\}$/{`. Note that your script needs to be run with `sed -n`.

Answer (score 1):

Get all range

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="end";FS="start"}{ print $NF}' file

content A


content B
```

Get 2nd range

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="end";FS="start"}{c++; if (c==2) print $NF}' file

content B
```

Ruby(1.9+), get first range

```
$ ruby -0777 -ne 'puts $_.scan(/start(.*?)end/m)[0]' file

content A
```

Comment: The other way, for traditionalists:) `awk '/start/{c++}c==n&&/start/,/end/'`

Comment: You can `print FS $NF RS` if you want the block markers included in the output.